# Why I m getting "Out Of Memory error" while processing huge file(3Gb) file using Perl online replacer comment

Tags: perl

I am using the below mentioned code to process a file. Even thought I have enough space to process the file I am getting out of memory. The same script works fine for small files.

```
#!/bin/ksh 
Perl -p -i -e 's/....... replacer comment...../g'  bulk_file.xml;
Sleep 5
```

Comment: The memory usage will depend on the content of the file and what you're trying to replace, as well as how much memory you have available. To get a good answer, put as much information as you can into the question.

Comment: What does `Perl` run? Normally, the Perl interpreter is lower cased. Also, don't use regular expressions to process XML, use an XML aware tool. In Perl, you have [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) and [XML::Twig](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig) at your disposal.

Comment: How long is the longest line?

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty common for systems to limit the amount of meomory that a program can use. It prevents memory leaks from clogging up your system.  It’s possible that you’re running into this limit when using a 3GB file. At which point the system will terminate your script. On most Linux systems you can use the ulimit command to change this memory limit. You could also run top after starting your program to track the memory usage.